# Combining Screen Size and Density Value Files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Something is really wrong with Android.

I have one Device with a "Normal screen and MDPI" (LG Optimus 2X P990)
I have one Device with a "Normal scren and XHDPI" (Samsung Galaxy S3)

I try to have all layouts in one single folder, for all views. If I change the color/text/whatever on one view, it goes globally. To have that value such as a "Color" to be located in all different layout means I have to change all the files when changing something so rudimentary as a color, or textsize.
Then in each "values-normal, values-xhdpi, values-large" I have set all settings unique to that device.

Example "values-normal"

```
<dimen name="text_small">10sp</dimen>
```

Example "values-xhdpi":

```
<dimen name="text_small">4sp</dimen>
```

Example "values":

```
<dimen name="view_textview_title">@dimen/text_small</dimen>
```

Currently, the MDPI device doesn't load the values from the "Values" folder, only when added to "values-normal" and the XHDPI device doesn't load the "values-xhdpi" if there is a Normal folder.

Well, to say the least I can't optimize the App for two different devices. That's what wrong.

Cause, I read that the "Normal" folder overrides the "XHDPI" folder for a Normal screen device with XHDPI Density. But to be able to see the Title text I have to set the text on the XHDPI text size to something like "4sp" while on the Normal with MDPI it's about "10sp".

A higher density will multiply the value more, a lower - less. Am I right? Then this way there is no possible way to optimize an App for two different devices with just a Density change. Each screen size with it's density size needs it's text size.

So, my question is the following...

**Can I combine "values-xhdpi-normal" "values-mdpi-normal", "values-hdpi-normal" and such?**

Otherwise, I have to make the App ugly for some devices and look good on some. I like probably more like me, don't use "TextSize = 10" on the whole page. A title is a title, larger, a menu is a menu, smaller text, descriptions on a menu even smaller. There you go.

Reason I'm asking is because I don't wanna reset the current layout without it being possible, too much work for nothing otherwise and Eclipse is buggy enough with it's productive approach of having to add a single line just to force a reinstall when a library has changed or restart the whole environment for it to understand that something's changed - especially with Values!

Comment: In case someone's wondering, I work with the same Layout files. They will forever be the same. I want the App to look the same everywhere. This way I work with "dimens.xml" file instead and provide all sizes through there which is more optimal and if it can work correctly (nothing in Android seem to work correctly), way more productive.

Comment: Just experimenting a little, seems that "values-normal-xhdpi" works, but if a device DON'T have XHDPI but a Normal screen and "values-normal" exists - it will still use "values-normal-xhdpi" instead of "values-normal"... This is confusing..